# Convert UTC to different timezone

Tags: php, datetime

I have a GMT formatted date `15/10/2012` and when I run `strtotime()` on it it returns false. I've tried setting the default time zone, which doesn't change anything and I've even tried doing the following.

```
$date = new DateTime($formatted);
$date->setTimezone('Europe/London');
return $date->getTimestamp();
```

Still no result however.

Anyone got any ideas please?

Comment: GMT = UTC http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

Comment: @vascowhite `15/10/2012`

Comment: How exactly are you planning on applying a timezone on a **date**, with no **time**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $formatted);
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
return $date->getTimestamp();
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

edit: updated timezone syntax.

Answer (score 0):

strtotime does not accept that format. Please see accepted formats in http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Comment: you probably need to reformat it. as an ugly hack, you could do something like $date = implode('/', array_reverse(explode('/', $date)))